# how to get the distance between iPhone's camera lens center and imaging plane in real time for each frame?

Tags: ios, iphone, avfoundation

I am using AVFoundation framework to acquire each frame in continuous AF mode. so the distance between lens and imaging plane is dynamic according to some AF algorithms. I have to compute the distance for some reasons. Is that possible to get the distance by using AVFoundation API?

Comment: With a single camera this is impossible. On the plus models with dual cameras you might be able to do it. But this might yield in an answer to brought for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pre-iOS 11, I don't think anything like this exist. However, if you only need to target iOS 11 and upwards, you could have a look at the `AVDepthData` class.

Official documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avdepthdata).

Note that, as rckoenes states, this will only work for compatible devices (with dual camera).